# Posting a similar question

Tags: bug, asking-questions, exact-duplicates

I am trying to post a new question that differs only in five words (the only significant ones) from a pre-existing one. I get a warning, but if I press "submit" again, the system gets stuck loading.

Comment: I recommend that you contrive some additional changes.

Comment: +1; I've had the same happen to me. I've edited out the unnecessary parts of your question already.

Comment: @IsaacMoses As it has happened to Shokhet too, it is a real bug. One that [seemingly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65733/how-to-ask-multiple-similar-but-different-questions) does not exist on SE.

Comment: @NBZ That MSE question is so old that things may have changed to stop spammers without anyone noticing that post to update it.